# Accessibility scanner complaining about 'No text in label' - does the text in the span not qualify?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have the following code:

```html
<label class="switch">
  <span class="accessibilityLabel">Grayscale</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="AccessibilityToolsGrayscale" class="accessibilityToggles" data-cookieAndClass="accessibilityTools-grayscale">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

An accessibility scanner built into our CMS is complaining that there is no text in the label. Does the span with 'Grayscale' as the  text not qualify as label text? How should my markup change to address the "missing" text in this case?

Comment: Smells like a bug in the (unspecified) scanner to me. Your live demo shows that browsers (at least) associate the text with the input (you can click on the text to toggle the checkbox).

Comment: OK - thats what I was wondering. idk that the unspecified tool as a name, its baked into our CMS (Omni CMS)

A tool like WAVE however doesn't complain at all, and in fact states that its valid.

Comment: It might also depend on what your *"accessibilityLabel"* class does on the `<span>`.  If it has something like `display:none`, then the text for your label would not be in the accessibility tree and the checkbox would indeed **not** have a label.

Comment: height: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;